# Cloudformation - ECRImageURI failed to satisfy constraint

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecr

I have a parameter for an ECRImage URI. When I try to test with a dry run with taskcat, I get the following error

`[ERROR  ] : ClientError An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameter ECRImageURI failed to satisfy constraint: Allow all characters`

But my regular expression for the pattern is already very lenient. Thoughts?

```
  ECRImageURI:
    AllowedPattern: ".*"
    ConstraintDescription: "Allow all characters"
    Default: 'http://464139160630.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/www.pulliam.sh:latest'
    Description: ECR Docker image to use in ECS Task definition.
    MaxLength: '64'
    MinLength: '1'
    Type: String
```

Edit:
Based on the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-regexes.html), Cloudformation uses [Java regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). So I can only conclude there is some issue with taskcat, or something else going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex pattern is satisfied, although `^.*$` would probably be a bit more expressive. But the actual problem seems to be with the `MaxLength` parameter. For instance, your default value already violates the length limitation.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks